# Efficiently update prices for multiple products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, database, price, multiple

I have been writing a module to update the prices of an arbitrary set of products based on specific criteria. My problem is that, the update of the prices seems to be very slow. I have been using `ProductRepository` to handle this, below is a sample code:

```
$result = $this->productRepository->getList($this->
$products = $result->getItems();
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->setPrice(67.74);
    $this->productRepositoryInterface->save($product);
}
```

Saving the price for 2000+ products takes about 3 minutes. I suspect that every `save` call makes a separate operation on the db.

For comparison, merely fetching the products and printing them in a file takes mere seconds.

I'd like to know if there is a way to bulk save the products after all the prices have been set.

Also, normally the above operations (again, I guess each and every save) trigger the indexer, thus the operation takes forever to finish unless I have the indexer set to `schedule` instead of `realtime`. If possible, I would also like a solution about bypassing the indexer for the duration of the script only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\Magento\Catalog\Api\BasePriceStorageInterface` is designed for quick price updates.
You need to specify only sku, store id, and price of product and this API allow to do it in batch.

What the `BasePriceStorageInterface` `update` function gets as parameter is an array whose elements are of type `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\BasePriceInterface`, and you need a `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\BasePriceInterfaceFactory` injected in your class to call its `create` function for each product you wish to update. `BasePriceInterface` has `setPrice, setStoreId, setSku` and `setExtensionAttributes` to set the respective values before putting the element in the array. The respective `get...` functions exist too. The `update` function updates the data given in the array atomically in the database and does not trigger the indexer until it is finished.

Comment: Editing your answer for whoever finds the question later.

Comment: @NoobDoob, thanks for the valuable update

Comment: I found this answer very helpful. But the issue is it is not updating prices for OOS products. Because of this, all product prices are not getting updated.